# CakePHP Find A Field Within An Array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, field

I am currently using the CakePHP find('all') function to retrieve a number of fields from a database. I know how to use 'fields' => array('Model.Field') to limit the number of fields returned. However, the function is currently returning data that looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
      'Model' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=8)
              'Field1' => string 'value'
              'Field2' => string 'value'
              'Field3' => string 'value'
              'Field4' => string 'value'
              'Field5' => string 'value'
              'Field6' => string 'value'
              'Field7' => string 'value'
              'Field8' => string 'value'
```

I want to return only some of these fields. I cannot find the syntax to accomplish this though. I have tried the following options:

```
'Model.Field1' (returns false)
'Model.0.Field1' (returns false)
'Model.[0].Field1' (returns false)
'Model' => 0 => 'Field1' (invalid syntax)
'Model' => '0.Field1' (returns false)
```

Is there a way to do this with the find function, or am I better off just writing my own SQL queries?

Edit: here is the find function as requested -

```
$this->Model1->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'restrict' => array('Model1', 'Model2', 'Model3', 'Model4'),
                'fields' => array('Model1.Field1', 'Model1.Field2', 'Model1.Field3', 'Model1.Field4', 'Model1.Field5', 'Model1.Field6', 'Model1.Field7',
                    'Model2.Field1', 'Model2.Field2', 'Model2.Field3', 'Model2.contract_id', 'Model2.Field4')
            ));
```

This currently works fine for limiting the results of Model1 and Model2 as they do not return the values within a subarray. As stated above trying to use the same syntax for Model3 and Model4 does not work. Here is what I tried to do using the "contain" option:

```
$this->Model1->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => $conditions,
                'restrict' => array('Model1', 'Model2', 'Model3', 'Model4'),
                'fields' => array('Model1.Field1', 'Model1.Field2', 'Model1.Field3', 'Model1.Field4', 'Model1.Field5', 'Model1.Field6', 'Model1.Field7',
                    'Model2.Field1', 'Model2.Field2', 'Model2.Field3', 'Model2.contract_id', 'Model2.Field4'),
                'contain' => array(
                    'Model3' => array(
                        'fields' => array(
                            'Field1',
                            'Field2',
                            'Field3',
                            'Field4',
                            'Field5',
                        )
                    )
                )
            ));
```

Comment: Could you post your full `find('all')`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to specify what fields are returned in the `find('all')`, as you mention in your question.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Model.Field1',
        'Model.Field2',
        // etc
    )
));
```

If `Model` is a related model, you can specify fields using the `ContainableBehavior`.

```
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Model' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Field1',
                'Field2', // etc
            )
        )
    )
));
```

[containable docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#)

Comment: I tried doing the approach you mention in the second block for Model3 and Model4, but it still returns all values instead of just the specified fields.